# What's the equivalent of Postgres' RAISE NOTICE in SQLServer 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking to output a message from a function in MS SQL 2005 when executed from the sql server management studio, similar to Postgres' RAISE NOTICE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise errors with RAISERROR, or print messages with PRINT. You should look these up in Books Online.

Answer (score 1):

It would be [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The direct translation may be RAISERROR, but SQL Server 2005 now supports TRY/CATCH blocks

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION TestTransaction

INSERT INTO tbBlah
(
    SomeColumn
)
VALUES
(
    5
)

COMMIT TRANSACTION TestTransaction
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TestTransaction
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres RAISE has:

> DEBUG, LOG, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, and EXCEPTION, with EXCEPTION being the default. EXCEPTION raises an error (which normally aborts the current transaction); the other levels only generate messages of different priority levels.
>
> [PostgreSQL Documentation 41.8. Errors and Messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)

The best equivalent to Raise Notice is probably `RaisError` *with a severity of 0*

```
RaisError 'Notice', 0,0
```